# Как работать с numba в питоне с использованием ClickHouse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clickhouse, numba

Пытаюсь работать с numba в питоне и не получается использовать  курсор базы данных. Использую
`request = client.execute_iter(base_req)`, причем создание курсора я пытался выносить в отдельную функцию, для которой не применял декоратор @njit, не помогло. Искал в документации numba clickhouse - ничего нет.
На этот код я получаю сообщение:

```
This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'clickhouse_driver.client.Client'>
```

По сути же, я в итераторе буду идти по этому курсору и получать обычные кортежи из двух элементов, с которыми numba работает. Как работать с numba, используя ClickHouse?
Описание задачи: происходит запрос к БД, из которой выгружаются кортежи из двух элементов, первый элемент - строка, второй число. Генерируется словарь, в качестве ключа которого выступают строки, а значения - списки из чисел, то есть происходит некая группировка по строкам. На текущий момент скорость заполнения словаря составляет примерно 500 000 строк в секунду.

```
d = defaultdict(list)
request = client.execute_iter(base_req)
{d[_i[1].lower()].append(_i[0]) for _i in tqdm.tqdm(request) if _i[0] not in d[_i[1].lower()]}
```

Запрос, к сожалению, показать не могу. Примерный результат вывода запроса: ("string", 5).

Comment: Приведите полный код

Comment: Ну сделайте какую-то функцию, которая будет брать из курсора и yield делать обычных кортежей. И пусть из этой функции данные читает уже функция с декоратором нумбы. А вообще - зачем вам нумба в этой задаче? Не очень понятно, даст ли она там что-то )

Comment: @CrazyElf, просто я в некотором затруднении касательно ускорения выгрузки из Clickhouse, так что даже обратился к numba, несмотря на то, что она предназначена в основном для арифметических операций, как я понимаю. Соблазнился описанным где-то ускорением кода в 40 раз. Наверное стоит удалить вопрос, раз тут приходится придумывать различные обертки?

Comment: @Сергей Вам просто нужно понять - у вас тормозит именно обработка того, что вы получаете из `Clickhouse` или может у вас сама выгрузка сырых данных из `Clickhouse` тормозит? Если второе, то тут `Numba` не поможет, надо с самой выгрузкой разбираться. А вот если обработка данных после выгрузки тормозит, тогда `Numba` может и помочь.

Comment: @CrazyElf я могу выгружать данные либо просто в список - тогда скорость выгрузки примерно 1,5 миллиона записей в секунду, либо, если я выгружаю в словарь с дополнительной обработкой в виде проверки уникальности его значений - скорость уже около 500 000 записей в секунду. Так что, кажется, проблема в обработке. Но если применять numba, то мне придется добавлять дополнительные операции по передачи в функцию кортежей из курсора и, возможно, еще что-нибудь, поэтому не факт, что numba что-то здесь ускорит.

Comment: @Сергей Вы бы показали всё же какой-то код. Если вы проверяете уникальность **значений** словаря, то вы как-то не так словарь используете. Надо делать такой словарь, чтобы проверять там ключи, а не значения, это происходит моментально. Либо может вам `set` подойдёт. Надо конкретизировать задачу и смотреть, сколько вообще значений у вас. А вы пытаетесь применить инструмент, который может вообще не для этой задачи совсем. Уточните задачу и тогда может поможем с подходящим инструментом.

Comment: @CrazyElf обновил, добавил код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот теперь хоть есть какой-то предмет (код) для разговора:

```
{d[_i[1].lower()].append(_i[0]) for _i in tqdm.tqdm(request) if _i[0] not in d[_i[1].lower()]}
```

1. Если вас интересует скорость - **не используйте `tqdm` во внутренних циклах обработки**! Если у вас есть какой-то внешний цикл - там можете использовать. А если вы оборачиваете самый внутренний цикл в `tqdm` - будьте готовы к значительному замедлению работы кода (вполне возможно, что всё замедление даёт вам именно `tqdm`). Возможно, с тех пор, как я всё это замерял прошло время и библиотеку немного улучшили, но работа с `GUI` всегда медленная и это также подтверждает мой личный опыт, что `tqdm` замедляет скорость работы кода в несколько раз.
2. У вас может по два раза осуществляться доступ к `d[_i[1].lower()]`, лучше занесите эту ссылку на список в отдельную переменную и делайте проверку и добавление через эту переменную. И функция `lower` тоже может работать не очень быстро, так что тут убьёте сразу двух зайцев.
3. Чтобы сделать изменение кода из п.2, вам видимо нужно отказаться от использования `включения множества` или что там у вас получилось через конструкцию `{ comprehension }`, тем более, что результат его вы всё-равно не используете, просто зря расходуя ресурсы на его генерацию - у вас получается там создаётся множество из элементов `None` (потому что `list.append` возвращает `None`), взятых в количестве элементов, возвращённых запросом. Всё это схлопывается в итоге в пустое множество. Зачем эта лишняя работа? Списковые (и прочие) включения - штука удобная и их можно и нужно использовать для выполнения небольших работ, но не в том, случае, когда речь идёт о миллионах записей и дорога каждая микросекунда, в этом случае надо тщательно смотреть, какой подход будет оптимальнее.

Так что предлагаю написать обычный прямой код, померить, с какой скоростью он будет работать и потом уже, если надо, думать дальше насчёт `Numba`, `lru_cache` или каких-то других улучшений:

```
for _i in request:
    l = d[_i[1].lower()]
    v = _i[0]
    if v not in l:
        l.append(v)
```

Кстати, вопрос - важен ли вам порядок элементов в списке, лежащем в словаре? Если нет, то сходу могу предложить использовать `defaultdict(set)` и `l.add(v)`, проверка на наличие элемента в коллекции будет работать значительно быстрее.

```
d = defaultdict(set)
for _i in request:
    l = d[_i[1].lower()]
    v = _i[0]
    if v not in l:
        l.add(v)
```

Comment: Порядок в списке не важен. Протестировал предложенный код, скорость не выросла, как скакала возле 500 тысяч, так и продолжила.

Comment: @Сергей Хм, тогда остаётся только грешить на сам `request = client.execute_iter(base_req)`, если просто по нему пройти `for`-ом без функционала внутри скорость вырастает в нормальную?

Comment: @Сергей Да, и как/чем вы меряете скорость? Не вносит ли мерилка сама замедление?

Comment: Проходился, используя for и замедляющий tqdm для оценки скорости. Без функционала скорость 1,5 миллиона. С функционалом - 500 тысяч. Так что дело не в request. Собственно, поэтому я и не грешу на tqdm, его уже довольно давно допилили до приемлемой скорости, плюс, возможно tqdm в jypiter работает медленнее, чем используемый в vs code.

Comment: @Сергей Хм, тогда у меня пока идеи кончились. Можно попытаться кормить несколько потоков разными порциями данных, чтобы каждый из них делал свой словарь и потом эти словари объединять.

Comment: Попробовал второй вариант со множествами. Скорость доходит до 700 тысяч, но периодически падает и до 300. Со списками более равномерно - 500-600 тысяч с редкими всплесками до тех же 700 и падениями до 400.
Касательно потоков, пробовал через multiprocessing, выигрыш в скорости заполнения нивелируется потерями на объединение полученных словарей.

Comment: @Сергей Ага, ну тогда я подозреваю, что у вас основное время тратится на выделение места под очередной кусок списка/множества. Судя по всему родные структуры Python делают regrowth неоптимально, особенно set.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113027/discussion-between--and-crazyelf).